# Use an eventlistener to check if a value has changed

Tags: javascript, html, input, counter, event-listener

I've created a check function where the code checks if a user has changed a value. If it has then a modal should be displayed if a value hasn't changed go back to the previous screen. The problem is that on some screens values are already existing so using the id to check this doesn't work.

Here are examples of the inputs:

```
                        <div class="govuk-input__wrapper"> <input
                                aria-label="Enter the total percetage for January. Enter 0 if this does not apply"
                                class="input-suffix govuk-input govuk-input--width-5" id="input-4"
                                onblur="sumPercentage()" name="installmentPercentage" type="text value=" value="5"
                                aria-describedby="percent">
                            <div class="govuk-input__suffix" aria-hidden="true">%</div>
                        </div>

                    <div class="govuk-form-group right-align">
                        <div class="govuk-input__wrapper">
                            <div class="govuk-input__prefix right-align" aria-hidden="true">£</div>
                            <input aria-label="Enter the total amount for February. Enter 0 if this does not apply"
                                class="govuk-input input-prefix govuk-input--width-7" id="input-3"
                                onblur="sumTotal()" name="installmentValue" type="text" aria-describedby="currency"
                                autocomplete="off" value="320,000">
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Every time this gets fired the input value for 'input4ValueChanged' and 'input3ValueChanged' is changed

```
document.getElementById("input-4").addEventListener("change", input4ValueChanged),
document.getElementById("input-3").addEventListener("change", input3ValueChanged),
```

Setting the input4WasChanged and input3WasChanged to false as we want to set it to true when the modal appears

```
function check() {

 let input4WasChanged = false
 let input3WasChanged = false
```

Starts the counter

```
 let counter = 0
```

If the input change is true then it opens the 'notSaved' modal

```
if (input4WasChanged === true) {
     document.getElementById('notSaved').style.display = 'block'
     counter++
 }
 if (input3WasChanged === true) {
     document.getElementById('notSaved').style.display = 'block'
     counter++
 }

 if (counter === 0) {
     history.back()
 }

}
```

If a value has been changed then display the modal

```
function input4ValueChanged(){
 if(document.getElementById("input-4").value != "")

 {
    input4WasChanged = true; 
 } 
}

function input3ValueChanged(){
 if(document.getElementById("input-4").value != "")

 {
    input3WasChanged = true; 
 } 
}
```

Comment: On the input I added onchange="input4ValueChanged()" which called the function when something on the input changed but not sure why it wasn't firing using the .addEventListener.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure of what you're asking here, but it seems that you've made a mistake in your Js or in your Html file.
Since your ids differs:

your js: `Boolean(document.getElementById(**"input-4"**).value),`

your html: `<input ... id="input-4 value=" ...>`

I hope I could help a bit.

Comment: Thanks, I've updated them now with 'input-4' but it's still not working as it still opens the modal without changing a value.

Comment: Pleasure helping :)
Just to be sure of the problem, you're trying to detect if the value of input-4, but you cant use the value attribut since there's a default value already?

If so, you could always use an eventlistener that set true a var "valueChangeInput4" and check for it instead of using you bool

Comment: Yes that's right I can't use the value because there is already a default value used. Would you be able to please provide an example of using an eventlistener?

Comment: Sure! (Might not be my cleanest code, but atleast it should give you an idea)

`document.getElementById("input-4").addEventListener("change", NAME_OF_YOUR_CUSTOM_FUNCTION_TO_SET_IT_TO_TRUE_HERE);`

and in your function just use a custom var

Comment: Thanks, like this then?

    function change(){
      if(document.getElementById("input-4").value != "")
      {
        return true;
      } else {
        return false;
      }
    }

Comment: Yep, maybe change a bit the name of your function to something a bit more unique or clearer. For example "function input4ValueChanged()" or something. 

But other than that everything seems good to me!

Comment: Still not working but if there is anything else that I can check please let me know.

Comment: oh my bad I just saw a probable mistake. Dont return the value. Create a new boolean and read it in to check if you have to change the style. And change your change function to something like that:

`function change(){ if(document.getElementById("input-4").value != "") { YOUR_VAR_HERE = true; } }`

Comment: Thanks, how would the VAR part work and connect to the other code. Would it just be var and then a number 'var 10'?

Comment: For exemple, if your var is called "input4WasChanged". You'd just have do (without using a for loop):
        `if (input4WasChanged === true) {
            document.getElementById('notSaved').style.display = 'block'
            counter++
        }`
Or
you could also use an array of booleans (if you really want to use a for loop)

Comment: So the whole function and the var would look like this then?

    var input4WasChanged = Number 


    function changed(){
        if (input4WasChanged === true) {             
            document.getElementById('notSaved').style.display = 'block'             
            counter++         
        }
    }

Comment: here I've made a [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/1yudY68D) with your code and the possible fix (for you to compare). Theres probably mistakes from my part, but it should guide you better.

Comment: Thanks, I took a look but don't understand what value to add in 'YOUR_VAR_HERE', any idea?

Comment: I've updated the code on the question.